# Add a key to existing json file

Tags: python, json

I've a very large JSON file(>60MB), which i was unable to open and edit in any editors. I see that we can do it using python.

Here is my sample data.

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon"
    },
    "id": "94601"
  },
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon"
    },
    "id": "94801"
  }
]
```

and my expected output is

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon"
    },
    "id": "94601"
  },
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon"
    },
    "id": "94801"
  }
]
}
```

I'm not sure of how can I do it in python. Here is the code that I'm using to read the file. But not sure of how to proceed further.

```
import json
f = open('/Users/Downloads/out_ca_california_zip_codes_geo.json', 'r')
out_file = open("/Users/Downloads/outNew_ca_california_zip_codes_geo.json", "w")
out_file.write(json.dumps(myFinalResult))
```

Thanks

Comment: `json` is a plain text format.  Will we can append text to the end of text file (e.g. new lines), we can't change the 'interior' of such a file without rewriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode your json which then become a Python dictionary then you can simply add your key to that, then re-encode and rewrite the file.

**Try this:**

```
import json

with open(json_file) as json_file:
    json_decoded = json.load(json_file)

json_decoded['ADDED_KEY'] = 'ADDED_VALUE'

with open(json_file, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_decoded, json_file)
```

For more details check here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html

Comment: Hi @Govind, thanks for quick response, what goes into Added_Value? 'coz it is the json file read :[(

Comment: So what is happening above is you decode your json which then become a Python dictionary then you can simply add your key to that, then re-encode and rewrite the file.

Comment: Here is the official doc, it will help you further https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html